# Key words to find for a "Yes" or N

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column with a lot of data, but I was wondering how can I find things with using key words (keywords below)?

*correction, *change, *legal, *property, terms, vesting, payment, date, interest, corr, amended, chg, address, exhiibit, add, notary, complete,amnt,

in no particular form would I need to find these and I was wondering if I can get maybe just a "Yes" or "No" type of answer.

Comment: i.e. you want to have a column flagging whenever any of the words exist in a cell?  I don't think you can do this without VBA although VBA would be simple. If that's OK i'll post an answer

Comment: You could string together a bunch of tests like `=NOT(ISERROR(FIND("correction",A1)>0)) + NOT(ISERROR(FIND("change",A1)>0)) + NOT(ISERROR(FIND("legal",A1)>0)) +NOT(ISERROR(FIND("property",A1)>0))... ` That's a heck of a mess though. I would agree with @LanaB that VBA is probably a better choice here. `instr()` would make quick work of this.

Comment: @JNevill The question is currently too vague to know the exact setup and desired result but a "formula only" solution could potentially be much cleaner with a reference table of keywords and probably an array formula.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff i'm super curious, i know the question has been answered, but maybe you could share yours?

Comment: @LanaB Ok I just posted an answer that will hopefully satisfy your curiosity. I think I explained it reasonably well and accurately but just comment on it if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer formula-only answers when they aren't unwieldy. All the formulas in this answer are array formulas and thus need <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when exiting the cell. Assuming keywords are in a range named KywrdTbl and the cell you want to search inside for keywords is A1, either of the following will determine whether A1 contains *any* keywords (1 for Yes; 0 for No):

```
=MAX(IFERROR(SIGN(FIND(KywrdTbl,$A1)),0))
=MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(KywrdTbl,$A1)),0,1))
```

To convert the output to Yes and No:

```
=IF(MAX(IFERROR(SIGN(FIND(KywrdTbl,$A1)),0))=1,"Yes","No")
```

And this will return the *number* of keywords found:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SIGN(FIND(KywrdTbl,$A1)),0))
```

So let's break down these formulas. The array aspect of the formula allows us to check each keyword independently (and then `SUM` or `MAX` their results). `FIND` returns an array of the character indices of each keyword in A1. `SIGN` then reduces each of those indices to 1 (since indices can't be negative). Then `IFERROR` swaps in a 0 for any cases where the keyword was not found. Finally we `SUM` up the number of 1's or take the `MAX` to find out if there are any 1's. The alternative in the first code block just replaces `IFERROR(SIGN(...),0)` with `IF(ISERROR(...),0,1)` thus explicitly assigning 1 to all found indices as opposed to using the `SIGN` trick.

Comment: b.h! That actually looks neat. Should look into array formulas perhaps.. I'll get my head around it on weekend, thank you for taking the time, Mark.

Comment: @LanaB Great!! When I take the time to draft an answer and test the formulas, it is always nice to know someone learned something from the answer. Certainly array formulas are a very useful tool to learn. They can simulate a VBA loop. And any time we can avoid VBA altogether, we have a more portable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Short of an ugly formula, you could use a VBA UDF for this.

```
Function containsWord(testCell As Range, wordList As String) As Boolean
    'loop through incoming list of words
    For Each testWord In Split(wordList, ",")
        'test to see if word is in the testCell
        If InStr(1, LCase(testCell.Value), LCase(testWord)) Then
            'if it is set the return to true and exit
            containsWord = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next testWord
End Function
```

To use this just create a new module and drop this code in, then you can use this function in a cell. If the cell you are testing for a word is A1 and the list of words is in B1 (comma separated) then:

```
=containsWord(A1,B1)
```